# Oracle SQL- Update with 2 joins

Tags: oracle11g

I've just joined this forum and have been following this for quite some time and sure does have a good feeling. 
I have a problem, wish someone could guide me.

My current code.

```
select *
  from T1 join T2 on T1C1 = T2C1 join T3 m on m.C3 = T2C3 join T3 n on n.C3 = T1C3 
 where m.C4 = 'EXHAUST'
   and T1C5 in ('NH', 'CA', 'FL')
```

I have to update `T1`, setting `T1C6 = 'CLEAR'`.

I tried various options, got an error on most of them. One worked however I got four times more records updated than the select statement. Here is what I tried.

```
update T1, set T1C6 = 'CLEAR' where exists (
    select *
      from T1 join T2 on T1C1 = T2C2 join T3 m on m.C3 = T2C3 join T3 n on n.C3 = T1C3
     where m.C4 = 'EXHAUST' and T1C5 in ('NH', 'CA', 'FL')
)
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: remove comma between `T1 and set`   UPDATE T1 `,` set

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with your update query is that ,there is no co-relations of update T1 with the exists clause in the statement ,so your whole T1 table records get updated irrelevant of the condition inside .If any of the record inside the exists clause satisy ,then it will update .Hence there must be some relation between the outer T1 with the inner sub query (Exists).Please find below the script .I dont know what you want to achieve this ,but this is how it should look like .Please test this .

```
UPDATE T1  set T1.C6 = 'CLEAR' where exists (
    select 1
      from T2 ,T3 m,T3 n 
     where T1.C1 = T2.C2
     AND   m.C3  = T2.C3
     AND   n.C3  = T1.C3
     AND   m.C4 = 'EXHAUST' 
     AND   T1.C5 IN  ('NH', 'CA', 'FL')
)
```

**EDIT** Its a weird ,and non optimized solution that the above,this solution is just for your understanding .

```
UPDATE T1  set T1.C6 = 'CLEAR' where T1.rowid IN (
select T1.rowid rd
  from T1,T2 ,T3 m,T3 n 
 where T1.C1 = T2.C2
 AND   m.C3  = T2.C3
 AND   n.C3  = T1.C3
 AND   m.C4 = 'EXHAUST' 
 AND   T1.C5 IN  ('NH', 'CA', 'FL'))
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, However I'm getting the same result, 4 times more records are updated even with your query. I believe we are doing the same thing only difference is I'm using the join command whereas yours dosent have it. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @redoctober:No there is a difference between your query and mine,i dint include T1 table in the inner query(from clause) ,because i need to find the relation between the row that is going to be updated satisfy the inner query or not ,Can you tell me what is the reason of joining `T1.C1 with T2.C2`

Comment: @redoctober:Just  do a simple test ,count the number of records in T1..`select count(*) from T1` and the count number of records from the query   `select count(*)
  from T1 join T2 on T1C1 = T2C1 join T3 m on m.C3 = T2C3 join T3 n on n.C3 = T1C3 
 where m.C4 = 'EXHAUST'
   and T1C5 in ('NH', 'CA', 'FL')` .The second count should not be more than the 1st count .plx check

Comment: Hi Gaurav, Thanks for your help once again. Yes, i did the count and the 2nd is less than the 1st, so that part is ok. I had to join T1C1 to T2C2 since I needed that join to proceed to get data from T3. However than being said, in your SQL you did not take T1 but we do have to since its part of the where statement. Any further suggestions if you can. Thanks

Comment: @redoctober:As you have seen in my sql ,i am considering T1 inside the query ,because some how we need to relate the table T1 with the inner query ,and this way my query will update only those records that the second query in our test shows ,if you're finding it difficult to understand correlated queries , please have a look in oracle doc web and mean time ,i will update an answer that is weird but understandable to you.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, Thanks for your help. However what do you  mean by "select T1.rowid rd" ..which rowId are you talking about?

Comment: @redoctober:please read this article :http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/concepts/rowid.html